# How to efficiently cover a set of points with circles when you can't access point coordinates?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, set, trigonometry

Suppose I have a finite set of points distributed in a unit square. I can't access the point coordinates; instead, I can only specify a (point, radius) pair and see how many points fall inside that circle. I want to find a set of circles such that each point is in at least one circle, and no circle contains more than 1000 points. What's an efficient way to do this? E.g. a way that minimizes the expected number of (point, radius) searches?

I tried a recursive approach. E.g. f(point, radius) takes a circle and returns a set of smaller circles that cover it. Then recurse until each circle contains fewer than 1000 points. But there's not a straightforward (to me) way to choose the smaller circles in the recursive step.

Edit: Circles are allowed to overlap with each other / with the outside of the square.

Comment: Is it even possible to partition ("partition" in the technical sense... cover every point in exactly one subregion) using circular subregions?  My intuition says no. If I'm right about that, to solve this, we'd need to be assured some minimum distance between the points.

Comment: Well technically you can partition by drawing a sufficiently small circle around each point — this just follows from the separability of R^2 right? But also my problem doesn't require a partition e.g. points can be contained in more than one circle.

Comment: Can parts of the circles go outside the unit square?

Comment: @Dave Yes I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: The simple thing to do is divide the original square into four smaller squares, and then check the circumcircle for each square. If the circumcircle has too many points, then recurse. The slightly harder approach is to use hexagons. The advantage of hexagons is that they are a much better approximation to a circle. The area of the circumcircle is 1.21 times the area of an enclosed hexagon, compared to 1.57 times the area of an enclosed square. The disadvantage is that tiling a hexagon with smaller hexagons requires 13 smaller hexes, 7 fully within and 6 overlapping. So more bookkeeping.

Comment: Two clarifications: 1) When you pick a point, radius pair, does the point have to be one of your input points or can you pick an arbitrary coordinate, radius pair?  2) When you pick a point, radius pair, is the information you get back just the count of covered points, or do you know which points are covered (by the newly created circle)?

Comment: Also note that this isn't so much a programming question as it is [a maths question](https://math.stackexchange.com). So this is kind of the wrong place to ask (for now. Once you start implementing it, and the code's not doing what you expect it to, this might be the right place to ask for help)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans See the second bullet point; algorithms questions are on-topic for S/O. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: They can be, but https://math.stackexchange.com is by far the better place to ask here (and if you want answers, you post to the best place first, with SO as your fallback. Either after not getting an answer for a while, or by cross posting).

Answer (score 1):

Not having a strict partition ("strict" - where the circles in the solution may not overlap and points must appear in exactly 1 circle) simplifies the problem.

The straight-forward way to subdivide a circle under those circumstances is to form a set of child circles that circumscribe the four quadrants of the parent...

[image]

Here's a (cursorily tested) demo using that approach

```js
class Circle {
  constructor(x,y,radius) {
    Object.assign(this, { x, y, radius })
    this.rSquared = radius*radius
  }

  contains(point) {
    let dx = point.x - this.x
    let dy = point.y - this.y
    return dx*dx + dy*dy < this.rSquared
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();  
  }

  subdivide() {
    const halfR = this.radius / 2.0
    const smallR = this.radius * Math.SQRT2 / 2.0

    return [
      new Circle(this.x-halfR, this.y-halfR, smallR),
      new Circle(this.x-halfR, this.y+halfR, smallR),
      new Circle(this.x+halfR, this.y-halfR, smallR),
      new Circle(this.x+halfR, this.y+halfR, smallR),
    ]
  }

}

// this class keeps a set of random points and answers countInCircle() 
// solutions may only call countInCircle() 
class Puzzler {
  constructor(count) {
    this.points = []

    for (let i=0; i<count; i++) {
      let point = { x: Math.random()*width, y: Math.random()*height}
      this.points.push(point)
    }
  }

  // answer how many points fall inside circle
  countInCircle(circle) {
    return this.points.reduce((total, p) => total += circle.contains(p) ? 1 : 0, 0);
  }

  drawSolution(circles) {
    // draw the random points
    this.points.map(p => ctx.fillRect(p.x,p.y,2,2))
    
    // draw the circles in the solution
    ctx.strokeStyle =  'lightgray'
    circles.forEach(circle => circle.draw())

    // log some stats - commented a few of these out for snippet brevity
    const counts = circles.map(circle => this.countInCircle(circle));
    console.log('circles:', circles.length)
    // console.log('counts:', counts.join(', '))
    // console.log('counts above 100:', counts.filter(c => c > 100).length)

    const averageCount = counts.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / counts.length
    console.log('average count:', averageCount.toFixed(2))

    const uncovered = this.points.reduce((total, point) => {
      return total + (circles.some(circle => circle.contains(point)) ? 0 : 1)
    }, 0)
    console.log('uncovered points:', uncovered)
  }

}

// setup canvas
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const { width, height } = canvas
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// setup puzzle
const count = 1000
const maxCountPer = 100
const puzzler = new Puzzler(count, maxCountPer)

// begin with an encompasing circle, subdivide and solve recursively
// until all subdivided circles meet the count criterion
let r = width*Math.SQRT2/2
let c = new Circle(width/2.0, width/2.0, r)
let solution = solve(c);

function solve(circle) {
  let result = []
  let count = puzzler.countInCircle(circle)
  if (count > 0 && count <= maxCountPer) {
    result.push(circle);
  } else if (count > maxCountPer) {
    circle.subdivide().forEach(c => {
      result.push(...solve(c))
    })
  }
  return result
}

requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  puzzler.drawSolution(solution)
});
```

```html
<h1>Circles Puzzle</h1>
 <canvas style="border: 1px solid gray;" id="canvas" height="800" width="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a valid approach. Personally, I would slightly oversize the smaller circles, to avoid any issues with floating point rounding errors: `smallR = this.radius * 0.71` An exaggerated example of the problem is shown on the right side of the image. A number of pixels that are contained within the parent circle are not contained in within the smaller circles.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: When you pick a point and a radius, you get back a list of points that are in the containing circle. I.e., you know which points are covered by which circles.

If that's correct,then you can map out the approximate relative location of all points, after which answers to this [similar question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63697/minimize-number-of-circles-to-cover-set-of-points) should carry you over the finish line.

To map out the relative location of all points:

Note that you can find the distance between any pair of points by centering your circle on one and using binary search on your radius to find the distance to the other within whatever precision you want to use.

Next choose three arbitrary points that aren't too close together. Pick an arbitrary point. Grow the radius, say to 1/4. Pick an arbitrary point close to that radius (by incrementing radius a bit to get another point, or using binary search on radius). Say the distance between these first two points is d. Pick a third point at distance >= d from the first two points but ideally close to d, again by incrementing the two radii or binary search on the same.

Now you have a roughly equilateral triangle. It isn't important that it's equilateral, but it is important that the points aren't very close, and aren't co-linear.

Next, give these three points coordinates. Say the first point is at (0,0), the second point is at (0, dist to first point). The third point will have two possible locations based on its distance from the first two. Choose the one in the first quadrant (arbitrarily).

All other points can now be positioned relative to this triangle by finding their distance two the points of the triangle.

For purposes of your problem, it doesn't matter that the cloud of points is rotated relative to the input, or that we don't know where the unit square is relative to the points. You have a cloud of points with (approximately) known coordinates, and can proceed accordingly.

Comment: If the assumption at the beginning of this answer was valid, then the correct approach would be to start with the circumcircle that contains the unit square, and get a list of all the points.

Comment: @user3386109 You already have all points, but don't have access to their coordinates.

Comment: @user3386109 ... at least, that's how I read the question; possibly mistaken. I believe you'd just get the list of all points back that you already have, without their coordinates.

Comment: @user3386109 The OP explicitly states that you can't get the point coordinates. If you also can't get the list of points inside containing circles, but only the counts, then I don't think this problem has a good solution since you'll never know which points are covered.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that you only get the count of points inside the circle. In which case, the task is to find a set of overlapping circles that cover the entire unit square, where each circle is small enough that it covers less than 1000 points. I agree that it's not an easy geometry problem, but it certainly can be solved.

Comment: Possibly you don't need to cover the unit square because all points may be in some tiny area within it. Disregarding that, if all you get is the count then in order to cover the unit square you need to be able to center your containing circles at known coordinates. That is, if the containing circles have to be centered at points that you don't know the coordinates of, then you have no way of knowing when you've covered the unit square or all the points.

Comment: You certainly can know when you've covered the entire unit square. Divide the unit square into quadrants. Cover each quadrant with its circumcircle, and you've covered the entire unit square with four overlapping circles. If exactly one of those circles has too many points, divide the underlying square into quadrants, and cover each of the four sub-quadrants with a circumcircle. Now you have three large circles and four smaller circles. Those 7 circles cover the entire unit square.

Comment: @user3386109 How can you cover a quadrant if you can't center a circle at arbitrary coordinates? If circles have to be centered at points and points have unknown coordinates then this doesn't work.

Comment: You seem to be using the word "point" to mean two different things. There are the "finite set of **points** distributed in a unit square." You don't know the coordinates of any of those. Let's call those the "target points". Then there's "I can only specify a (**point**, radius) pair and see how many ..." Let's call those the "circle centers". Circle centers are arbitrary, and specified by you. Target points are fixed, predetermined, and unknown.

Comment: Oh, rereading my comment, I see what you're thinking. You are actually using the the word "point" to always mean "target point". I'm the one using "point" to mean two different things, lol. Only allowing "circle centers" to be located at "target points" does indeed result in an entirely different problem.